# Scrolling with mouse drag inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scrollable list. It has the overflow-y property set to scroll and I can scroll with the scroll bar but I would like to be able to use my mouse to drag up and down.

Here is what I have so far

```
    //Allows the user to scroll by dragging the mouse
    element.on({
        'mousemove': function(e)
        {
            if (self.get('clicked'))
            {
                const difference = self.get('clickY') - element.scrollTop();
                const scrollY = difference + (e.pageY - element.offset().top);
                element.scrollTop(scrollY);
            }
        },
        'mousedown': function (e)
        {
            const clickY = (e.pageY - element.offset().top) + element.scrollTop();

            self.set('clicked', true);
            self.set('clickY', clickY);
        },
        'mouseup': function (e)
        {
            self.set('clicked', false);
        },
        'mouseleave': function(e)
        {
            self.set('clicked', false);
        }
    });
```

I have been playing around with it but just cant get it right, because I have to take into consideration the y position of the element, how much its already scrolled, the mouseY etc. Would someone be able to help me out with this please?

Comment: You don't need to take the page scroll etc. into account. Get the mouse Y coordinate on mouseClick and store in a local variable. Then just get the difference on mouseMove between original Y position and new Y position. Exactly the same for the scrollable area. Sorry don't have time to write an example for you but I think you will get it from this.

Comment: Thanks i got it now :)